# jQuery JSON data use single response from array

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to populate 2 areas of a section from a JSON response. The response works and outputs the following, however when I try to use data[0] and data[1] to get the title, text and image it doesn't want to. I am getting the data back correctly, just can't seem to add it in.The console.log response is undefined.

JSON Response:

```
[{"title":"Title 1","text":"Text 1","image":"Image 1"},{"title":"Title 2","text":"Text 2","image":"Image 2"}]
```

jQuery code:

```
$.get( 'test-api.php?eventQuery', { answers }, function( data, status ) {
    console.log(data[0].title);
    // Populate both sections with returned data
});
```

Comment: You're sending it as a `string` or as a `json`? Did you tried to use `JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: Use `getJSON` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this

```
$.get( 'test-api.php?eventQuery', { answers }, function( data, status ) {
                console.log(data[0].title);
                    // Populate both sections with returned data


            },"json");
```

or

```
$.get( 'test-api.php?eventQuery', { answers }, function( data, status ) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data[0].title);
                    // Populate both sections with returned data


            });
```

Comment: I just solved it myself using: var eventData = JSON.parse(data);
                        console.log(eventData[0].title); Thanks :)